# Variable length int C++

Tags: c++, int, overflow, ram

I have a program that takes in a file that is just a list of sets, each with their own integer identifier, and then sorts the sets by the number of members.

File format (the number after R is the ID):

R1

0123

0000

R2

0321

R3

0002

...

```
struct CodeBook {
   string Residue; //stores the R lines
   vector<string> CodeWords; //stores the lines between the R lines
};

vector<CodeBook> DATA;
```

With each file I run, the number of sets gets larger, and currently I am just storing everything into the huge vector DATA. My latest file is large enough that I've taken over the server's memory and flowing over into swap. This will be the last file I process before I possibly switch to a more RAM-friendly algorithm. With that file, the number of sets is larger than an unsigned 32 byte int.

I can calc how many there will be, and the number of sets is important for calculation purposes, so overflow is not an option. Going all the way up to a unsigned long long int is not an option either, because I've already pretty much maxed out memory usage.

How could I implement a variable length integer to more efficiently store everything so I can more efficiently calc everything?

Ex: small id ints get 1 or 2 bytes and the largest ints get 5 bytes

PS: Given the size of what I'm working with, speed is also a factor if it can be helped, but it's not the most important concern :/

Comment: Of course you could define your own class that allocates exactly the memory as needed and implement all the needed operations (multiplication, addition, assignment ....). But maybe (if you tell us more about your algorithm) another, more ram-friendly solution is of greater help.

Comment: Hang on .. I'm sure I've seen this question before. And Anedar's exact comment.... am I losing the plot?!

Comment: Have I got this right: Your file contains an identifier (which fits in four bytes), and a count (which doesn't always fit in four bytes).  Is that right?

Comment: @MartinBonner The count is the ID, and the count doesn't fit in 4 bytes, but using 8 bytes  makes no sense just because I'm overflowing by 1 or two digits.

Comment: So what are your "sets"?  `CodeBooks`, `CodeBooks`, or `CodeWords`?

Comment: @MartinBonner Have I made it more clear? sorry about the confusion

Comment: Jeff:  No.  Sorry.  I now don't see any ints in your data structures at all.  Just lots of strings.  This is actually good news - strings are much more complicated beasts, and hence the opportunities to write a special purpose class to hold them compactly much higher.

Answer (score 0):

Store everything in two huge vectors.

Define two structs with associated vectors:

```
struct u { int id; unsigned count };
struct ull { int id, unsigned long long count };

std::vector<u> u_vector;
std::vector<ull> ull_vector;
```

Read the count into an unsigned long long.  If the count fits in an unsigned, store it in `u_vector`, otherwise in `ull_vector`.  Sort both vectors; output `u_vector` first and `ull_vector` second.

Don't be tempted to try doing the same thing with `unsigned char` - the structure will be the same size as `u` (because of padding to make the `id` aligned).

Comment: "What could be worse than a giant paint bubble?!" "I know! TWO GIANT PAINT BUBBLES!"

Comment: But seriously, I think I might need to elucidate a bit more code, cause this is askew to my problem.